# vb.net - For Each (of the first 9 items) s In groupings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following line:

`For Each s In groupings`

What I want to do is get the first 9 items from groupings.

I tried `For 0 to 8 s In groupings` but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Take`:

```
For Each s In groupings.Take(9)
```

This will return the first 9 elements in groupings, i.e. indexes 0 to 8.

Update because of your question in the comments:

To get the items at positions 5 to 9, do this:

```
For Each s In groupings.Skip(5).Take(5)
```

This will skip the first 5 elements, i.e. indexes 0 to 4 and return the next 5 elements, i.e. indexes 5 to 9.

Comment: Didn't know that function. This is super neat.

Comment: Have a look here for a lot more of those neat methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to do Take(5 to 9)??

Comment: @Tom: Sure: groupings.Skip(5).Take(5). Explanation: 5 as parameter to Skip, because you want to skip the first 5 items, so you can access the 6th item at position 5. 5 as parameter to Take, because you want to take five elements: Element 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with Daniel Hilgarth answer, but just for your information, the way you're trying to do would look like this :

```
For i as integer = 0 to 8
   dim s = groupings(i)
   ...
Next i
```

Comment: This is pretty much the method I was trying to work out +1! Really like Daniels method too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a counter initialized to 0

```
For Each s In groupings
    counter =counter+1
    .....
    If counter=9 Then
    Exit For
Next
```

(check it, I forgot the syntax)